# What's the command of getting the Api response time

Tags: bash, postman

What's the command of getting the Api response time just like in post man.

[image]

just like in the postman it show 93ms.

I want to get that when curl in my terminal.

Comment: You really felt it necessary to post that gigantic image of unrelated content in order to show the tiny little value that takes up about 1% of that entire image? I'm reading on a laptop with a fairly good screen, and had difficulty spotting it even after viewing full screen in that status bar across the top of the tabs above the JSON. Imagine how someone reading this question on a tablet or smartphone is going to feel when they've had to download all of the data  in the irrelevant content in order to try to spot that little, barely highlighted spot on the faaaaaar right edge.

Comment: You felt the need to write such a long comment to say "Attach a more specific image next time". Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try this [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) command :

```
time curl http://10.10.5.242/api/v1/incidents/
```

Comment: the output is 
`real 0m0.006s
user 0m0.000s
sys 0m0.005s`

Comment: Take account only with the first one

Comment: bloat ware is not more quicker